# How to extract numbers from text?

Tags: r, character, strsplit

i have the flowing text string:

```
string <- "['CBOE SHORT-TERM VIX FUTURE DEC 2016', 81.64],\n\n    ['CBOE SHORT-TERM VIX FUTURE JAN 2017', 18.36]"
```

is there a simple way of extracting numerical elements from text without having to use:

```
string_table <- strsplit(string, " ")
```

and then select n-th element and continue to `strsplit` until i have what i need.

the result should be:

```
result <- c(2016, 81, 64, 2017, 18, 36)
```

thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can use `str_extract_all` by specifying the pattern as one or more number (`[0-9]+`).  The output will be a `list` of length 1, extract the vector with `[[` and convert to `numeric`.

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(str_extract_all(string, "[0-9]+")[[1]])
#[1] 2016   81   64 2017   18   36
```

If we are using `strsplit`, split by the non-numeric characters

```
as.numeric(strsplit(string, "\\D+")[[1]][-1])
#[1] 2016   81   64 2017   18   36
```

Comment: In the first you are searching for all numbers 0 to 9. could you please explain what the + is for. same question for "\\D+" if you could explain the logic there that would b great. Thank you very much for the quick answer .

Comment: @AlexBădoi  The `\\D+` specifies one or more non-numeric characters