# Strip out numbers from text: R

Tags: r, regex

hello i having the data set which consists to text, whole numbers and decimal numbers, text is a paragraph which will be having all this mix, trying to strip out only the whole numbers and decimal numbers out of the text content, there are about 30k trow entries.

input format of data:

1. This. Is a good 13 part. of 135.67 code
2. how to strip 66.8 in the content 6879
3. get the numbers 3475.5  from. The data. 879 in this 369426

Output:

1. `13 135.67`
2. `66.8 6879`
3. `3475.5 879 369426`

i tried replace all alphabets one by one, but 26+26 replace all is making code lengthy, and replacing "." replaces "." from the numbers also
Thanks,
Praveen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278296/extract-numbers-from-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option using `strsplit` to split in separate lines and then use `gsub` to replace `[:alpha]` following `.` or  or just `[:alpha]`.

```
text <- "1. This. Is a good 13 part. of 135.67 code
2. how to strip 66.8 in the content 6879
3. get the numbers 3475.5 from. The data. 879 in this 369426"

lines <- strsplit(text, split = "\n")[[1]]
gsub("[[:alpha:]]+\\.|[[:alpha:]]+\\s*","",lines)
#[1] "1.  13  135.67 "       
#[2] "2. 66.8 6879"          
#[3] "3. 3475.5   879 369426"
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that `R` has already inbuilt regex functions:

```
input <- c('This. Is a good 13 part. of 135.67 code', 'how to strip 66.8 in the content 6879',
           'get the numbers 3475.5 from. The data. 879 in this 369426')

m <- gregexpr('\\b\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?\\b', input)
(output <- lapply(regmatches(input, m), as.numeric))
```

This yields

```
[[1]]
[1]  13.00 135.67

[[2]]
[1]   66.8 6879.0

[[3]]
[1]   3475.5    879.0 369426.0
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
library(stringr)
lapply(str_extract_all(a, "[0-9.]+"), function(x) as.numeric(x)[!is.na(as.numeric(x))])
[[1]]
[1]  13.00 135.67

[[2]]
[1]   66.8 6879.0

[[3]]
[1]   3475.5    879.0 369426.0
```

The basic idea is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40744463/how-to-extract-numbers-from-text) but we include the `.`. The `lapply` transforms to numeric and excludes `NA`'s

The data:

```
a <- c("This. Is a good 13 part. of 135.67 code",
       "how to strip 66.8 in the content 6879",
       "get the numbers 3475.5 from. The data. 879 in this 369426")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method with `gsub`:

```
string = c('This. Is a good 13 part. of 135.67 code', 
           'how to strip 66.8 in the content 6879',
           'get the numbers 3475.5 from. The data. 879 in this 369426')

trimws(gsub('[\\p{L}\\.\\s](?!\\d)+', '', string, perl = TRUE))
# [1] "13 135.67"         "66.8 6879"         "3475.5 879 369426"
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution free of regex and external packages:

```
sapply(
  strsplit(input, " "),
  function(x) {
    x <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x))
    paste(x[!is.na(x)], collapse = " ")
  }
)
[1] "13 135.67"         "66.8 6879"         "3475.5 879 369426"
```